# How to send an email because I HAVE SO MANY ERRORS. Thanks

Tags: windows, vb.net, email

I recently made a system / registration form. And I created a "sub" to generate a random key. Then I want to send it by email. I create this code:

```
    SerSMTP()
    Dim SrvSMTP As String = Serv.Text

    Dim MessageText As String = "Test 1212! Good!"

    Try
        Dim MyMailMessage As New MailMessage()
        Dim SMTPServer As New SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com")

        MyMailMessage.From = New MailAddress("regikey@hotmail.com")
        MyMailMessage.To.Add(Adress.Text)
        MyMailMessage.Subject = ("Registration")
        MyMailMessage.Body = ("Your key is " & GenKey)

        SMTPServer.Port = ("993") 'Port
        SMTPServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("regikey@hotmail.com", "Idontwanttoshowthepasswordsorry!")
        SMTPServer.EnableSsl = True

        SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage) 'Send
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Unable to send to email. Reason :" & ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

But I got a batch of error like: "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required" and so on.

What to do to make it work with the most compatibility?

thank you in advance

Sincerely, Loud

Comment: Port 993 is probably not correct if you're enabling SSL/TLS. It's usually either 465 or 587. You'll also likely find that these consumer mail like gmail, hotmail, outlook, yahoo, etc have limits that make them unsuitable for what you're trying to do. You'll either need to setup your own mail server (not at all fun) or get a paid account with an email provider that has better support for business mail.

Comment: Whatever port is correct, .Port is expecting an Integer not a String. `SMTPServer.Port = 993`

Comment: Port 993 is for IMAP, why is definitely not SMTP

Comment: Start off by downloading `smtp4dev` and using it as a mail server. It's a local program that fakes an SMTP server so you can test your code works locally before shelling out for one

Comment: But how to do it?